# Stumped on python looping and data dictionaries

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, loop

I have been stumped getting my python code to work for a while now. I've been using python for the last several years on and off for simple things, but I am far from an expert in python. I am trying to create a loop that cycles through specific folders and reprojects all rasters in each particular folder into a new specified empty folder in a different location, then I need the program to do the same for the next specified folder and so on. Below is my stripped down code with my specified input and output folder locations. I was thinking a data dictionary would be best here but I couldn't get the dictionary to run with the loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much in advance!

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Load required toolboxes...
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

arcpy.env.workspace = "z:\\z11_10m\\"

input_wksp = ["z:\\z11_10m\\s41120",
              "z:\\z11_10m\\s42120",
              "z:\\z11_10m\\s42121",
              "z:\\z11_10m\\s43120",
              "z:\\z11_10m\\s43121",
              "z:\\z11_10m\\s44120",
              "z:\\z11_10m\\s44121"]

out_wksp = {"z:\\z11_10m\\project\\s41120\\",
            "z:\\z11_10m\\project\\s42120\\",
            "z:\\z11_10m\\project\\s42121\\",
            "z:\\z11_10m\\project\\s43120\\",
            "z:\\z11_10m\\project\\s43121\\",
            "z:\\z11_10m\\project\\s44120\\",
            "z:\\z11_10m\\project\\s44121\\"}

for rast in arcpy.ListRasters("*"):
    arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(rast, out_wksp + rast, "PROJCS['NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_11N',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-117.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "NEAREST", "10", "", "", "PROJCS['NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-123.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]")
    print rast, "projected and extracted"

print "finished"
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not something like this:

```
folders = ["s41120", "s42120", "s42121", "s43120",
           "s43121", "s44120", "s44121"]

path = r'z:\z11_10m'

for folder in folders:
    working = os.path.join(path, folder)
    outworking = os.path.join(path, "project", folder)
    arcpy.workspace = working
    for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("*"):
        outname = os.path.join(outworking, rast)
        arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(rast, outname)
```

Or like this

```
folders = ["s41120","s42120","s42121","s43120",
          "s43121","s44120","s44121"]

path = r'z:\z11_10m'

inpaths = (os.path.join(path, folder) for folder in folders)
outpaths = (os.path.join(path, "project" folder) for folder in folders)

for working, outworking in zip(inpaths, outpaths):
    arcpy.workspace = working
    for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("*"):
        outname = os.path.join(outworking, rast)
        arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(rast, outname)
```

Choose your style.  This is a functional style using generators for lazy evaluation:

```
from itertools import imap
from os.path import join

path = r'z:\z11_10m'
folders = ["s41120","s42120","s42121","s43120", "s43121","s44120","s44121"]
paths = ((join(path, folder), join(path, "project") for folder in folders)
projection = "Your proj string"

def project((rast, out)):
    arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(rast, out, projection)

def getrasters((working, outworking)):
    arcpy.workspace = working
    rasters = ((rast, join(outworking, rast)) for rast in arcpy.ListRasters("*"))
    return rasters

rasters = imap(getrasters, paths)
imap(project, rasters)
```

*Note:* `imap`, and how paths now returns a tuple of in and out paths.

Comment: This is assuming that the out folder is just the same path but with `\project\foldername` on the end.

Comment: Thanks Paul and everyone, I haven't quite been able to get the script to successfully run yet, however I have a lot of good information to give it a shot again tomorrow. Tomorrow is a new day. Thanks everyone so much for your help!

Comment: +1 for `os.path.join()` and a nifty implementation of `zip()`. I need to implement both so that I don't have to worry about slashes or using enumerate unnecessarily.

Comment: `os.path.join` also makes your code more portable...oh wait arcgis...never mind :) but it's still good practice.

Comment: Well I'm not surprised you're taking a stab at arcgis, haha. I'm all for FOSS and cross platform compatibility. It would be a good habit for me to form at any rate when and if arcgis is ported.

Comment: Nice work Nathan, @Paul & stumped - quite a few good Python lessons to learn all round on this one - I initially thought Paul had nailed it at the outset.

Comment: itertools is a goldmine, +1.

Comment: It's a pain we have to do `arcpy.workspace = working`. If `ListRasters` too a path we wouldn't need to wrap it in a method.